# Merge Two ABRecordRef contacts

Tags: ios, contacts

How can I merge two `ABRecordRef` records?

I mean I want to get all properties from one record and save it to the other record and delete the first one.

Comment: You have done this?
I Have a same problem.
@mohamede1945

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to iterate over all the properties and copy them over.

Comment: Thanks.. I have done this.. @mohamede1945

Comment: can someone post code solution here that worked?